# ¿Cómo pasar un parámetro en una función en PHP(lLaravel 8) y JavaScript?

Tags: php, laravel

¿Cómo puedo pasar el `id_productos` y lo lea el método `funcionId()`?, adjunto código:

```html
<td class="td">
  <button class="button" onclick='addToCarritoItem('{{$e->id_productos}}')> 
   Añadir
  </button>
</td>
```

mi intento es

onclick="funcionId('{{$e->id_productos}}')"

```
function funcionId(id){ 
   const button = id.target;
   const item = button.closest('.tr');

   const id_productos = item.querySelector('.id').textContent;}
```

Comment: Eso me parece que es Laravel o algo similar, que no sé como funcionará en el caso de las comillas y puede ser eso lo que te esta dando problemas, además que evidentemente estas llamando a la función `addToCarritoItem` en vez de a la función `funcionId`, entonces prueba algo así: `onclick="funcionId('{{$e->id_productos}}')"> `

Comment: Solo cambia `addToCarritoItem` por `funcionId`. saludos.

Comment: @Yussef no funciono

Comment: Agrega un console.log("ALGO") dentro de `funcionId` y mira si se ejecuta,

Comment: si se ejecuta, pero se termina altito, ago ve como uncahught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando necesites pasar datos de PHP a Javascript puedes insertar las etiquetas HTML desde PHP y de esa forma usando la concatenación de cadenas ó, lo que a mi parecer es más legible, usar la función printf.

[prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php](https://prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

La mejor manera de hacerlo sería evitar usar HTML puro, sino incrustar HTML desde PHP dentro de la función printf.

Te dejo un ejemplo en PHP donde se genera un número aleatorio y este número es enviado a una función de javascript que lanza una alerta mostrando que ha recibido el número desde PHP de forma correcta.

**NOTA:** No olvides que para que funcione el documento de PHP este debe de encontrarse en un servidor compatible con PHP, para mis pruebas yo utilizo este paquete de software que te instala Apache + PHP + MySQL:

[www.appserv.org](https://www.appserv.org/en/)

---

*index.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            # Generamos un número aleatorio y lo guardamos en una variable
            $id_producto = rand(0,100);
            # Imprimimos la variable para conocer el número generado
            printf('<p>El id del producto es: </p>' . $id_producto);
        ?>
        <br>
        <br>
        <td class="td">
            <?php
                # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
                printf('<button class="button" onclick="addToCarritoItem(' . $id_producto . ')">Añadir</button>');
            ?>
        </td>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

*script.js*

```
function addToCarritoItem(id)
{ 
    // Guardamos la variable en una constante de js
    const id_producto = id;
    // Creamos una alerta donde mostramos el contenido de la constante
    alert("El id del producto es: " + id_producto);
}
```

---

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando en el siguiente link:

**[Ver La Demo](https://paiza.io/projects/zd_iUs9svSJmmv_Xo2i1yg)**